# How do I get Android SDK to run?

Tags: android

When I try to start it up, an alert pops up saying "The environment variable JAVA_HOME does not point to a valid JVM station." I know how to change the environment variable, but I don't know what to change it to. Can anybody tell me how to find the correct path to the JVM installation?

Comment: Wherever you installed java.  Its going to differ by OS, even if you installed it in the default place.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 (for my case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how to find that.  Would you be able to tell me how to find that path?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the environment variable to point to your JDK installation. For example, mine is set to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer!  As I mentioned in another comment, I'm not sure exactly how to find that.  Would you be able to tell me how to find that path?

Comment: What operating system are you running? My answer was assuming you were running Windows. Another comment asked you what your operating system was so once you let us know we can help you further. It should be the root path of your JDK installation though.

Comment: You're right sorry about that, overlooked it.  It's Windows.

Comment: Then the path I gave you should work. If you installed the Java jdk it should install by default to the C drive in Program Files and be placed inside of a directory named Java. If you did a custom path or anything like that then you'd need to use that path. You may have a different version of the JDK so if you are copying and pasting the path then it may not work, find your Java folder and then find your jdk install within that folder. If you can't find it, then perhaps you didn't install it? The JDK is different from the JRE.